# Javascript remoting on custom object

Tags: apex, error, javascript-remoting

I have a custom object Feedback. I want to create a list of editable feedback records using Javascript Remoting. Following is my controller..

```
global with sharing class AccountRemoter {
public String accountName { get; set; }
public List <Feedback__c> account { get; set; }
public AccountRemoter() { }
@RemoteAction
global static Feedback__c getAccount(String accountName) {
List<Feedback__c> account = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Feedback__c ];
return account ;
 }
}
```

I'm getting the following error

> "Error: Compile Error: Return value must be of type:
>   SOBJECT:Feedback__c at line 8 column 8".

Please guide. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change declaration of method.

You put `Feedback__c` as returned value in declaration but you returning `List<Feedback__c>`

Comment: THnx for the heads up!